# How to Add two Number using Springboot thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

i am a beginner of spring boot thymeleaf form. i want to add two numbers to calculate and displayed total. i don't know how calculating values. i can post the values into **@PostMapping("/reg_success")**
so how can i calculating and display the total at reg_success.html page. what i tried so far i attached below.

i got the error of

```
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/index.html]")
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parse(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:241) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parseStandalone(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:100) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.parseAndProcess(TemplateManager.java:666) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1098) [thymeleaf-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1072) [thymeleaf-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:366) [thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:190) [thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.12.RELEASE.jar:3.0.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1393) [spring-webmvc-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1138) [spring-webmvc-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1077) [spring-webmvc-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:962) [spring-webmvc-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) [spring-webmvc-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) [spring-webmvc-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:626) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) [spring-webmvc-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) [tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) [spring-web-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) [spring-web-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) [spring-web-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.41.jar:9.0.41]
    at
```

**StudentContoller**

```
   @Controller
public class StudentContoller 
    {
    @GetMapping("/index")
    public String sendForm(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("student", new Student());
        return "index";
    }

    @PostMapping("/reg_success")
    public String processForm(@ModelAttribute Student student, BindingResult result, Model model)
    {
        model.addAttribute("student", student);
        return "reg_success";
    }
 
}
```

**Student.java**

```
  public class Student 
{
     private int num1;
     private int num2;
     
    public int getNum1() 
    {
        return num1;
    }
    public void setNum1(int num1) 
    {
        this.num1 = num1;
    }
    public int getNum2() 
    {
        return num2;
    }
    public void setNum2(int num2) 
    {
        this.num2 = num2;
    }
    
    public int getTotal() {
        return num1 + num2;
    }
}
```

**index.html**

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Add User</h1>

<form th:action="@{/reg_success}" th:object="${student}" method="post">
        Studnt ID: <input type="text" id="id" name="id" value="0">
    </p>
    
   <p>
    Num1 <input type="text" id="num1" th:field="*{num1}" name="num1" value="">
</p>
<p>
    Num2 <input type="text" id="num2" th:field="*{num2}" name="num2" value="">
</p> 
    
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/> <input type="reset" value="Reset">
    </p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**reg_success.html**

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Show message</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>

<h1>Result</h1>

<p th:text="${student.getTotal()}"></p>  





</body>
</html>
```

Comment: kindly see my updated answer, you gotta update the controller to `model.addAttribute("student", new Student());` in sendForm method

Comment: what i tried i updated code above still getting error sir

Comment: can you also post the error?

Comment: if the there is another using spring service add it sir it will helpful for me thanks

Comment: i need to see the error first in order to solve the initial problem

Comment: well i attached error above sir

Comment: You cutted index.html to a fragment, but as far as I saw it was missing the thymeleaf namespace entry `<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">`

Comment: i added it not workingggg

Comment: can you also post the entire code for index.html and your controller

Comment: i updated the index.html page above code

Comment: thanks sir workingggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg

Comment: sir may i know how to add the spring service to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

kindly update your **controller**:

```
@GetMapping("/index")
public String sendForm(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("student", new Student());
    return "index";
}
```

kindly change this code from **index.html**

```
<p>
    Num1 <input type="text" id="num1" name="num1" value="">
</p>
<p>
    Num2 <input type="text" id="num2" name="num2" value="">
</p>
```

to:

```
<p>
    Num1 <input type="text" id="num1" th:field="*{num1}" name="num1" value="">
</p>
<p>
    Num2 <input type="text" id="num2" th:field="*{num2}" name="num2" value="">
</p>
```

Add this method to your Student:

```
public int getTotal() {
    return num1 + num2;
}
```

And finally update on your **reg_success.html**:

```
<p th:text="${student.getTotal()}"></p>
```

**Note** that this solution is exclusive to your problem and for the future you might want to create services especially when you have to persist your entities.

Comment: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/index.html]")  i got the error when i changed

Comment: I will update my answer, i think i know why

Comment: sir may i know how to add the spring service to do this

Comment: you are now 17 reputation, i upvoted your question. you can upvote answers now :)

Comment: ok i did it may i know how to do the same example with spring service to do this

Comment: shall i post the new question for that will you help me????

Comment: thank you! actually it's a big task and you should try and read some documentations about it. you can start with this link: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-intro

Comment: start with some tutoirals and try it on your own first

Comment: i have done the services and all the stuff. i made the login form connect with database. if the login success visit to the home page. i did working successfully.my problem how to displayed session i tried not working please help me on that

Answer (score 0):

You can sum two variables like this.

```
<p th:text="${student.num1 + student.num2}"></p>
```